# Transferring form results to different page, and setting variable to source value

Tags: image, src

I've been working on this for a while now.

What i want is for the webpage to have a form, which asks for a url to an image, and once they input the url and click submit, it should go to a different page and should display the image on the page.

Help?

Also, is there any way to call the height and width of the image?

note: I CAN NOT USE ASP

Answer (score 1):

Your file with form
**form.html**

```
<form method='get' action='show_img.php'>
<input type='text' name='url' value='' /> URL
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Your file which recieve form data and show image:
**show_img.php**

```
<?php
$url_path = $_GET['url'];
// Don't forget to cheack if recieved data is SAFE!

echo "<img src={$url_path} />";

?>
```